# JFreeReport trying to dynamically set height of line item with a border around it

Tags: java, jfreereport

Using the JFreeReport classic engine, I have:

```
<items height="10" fontname="SansSerif" fontstyle="plain" fontsize="8">
    <rectangle x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="10" dynamic="true" color="#CCCCCC" fill="false" draw="true" />
    <string-field x="2" y="0" width="100%" height="10" dynamic="true" fieldname="Workorder #"/>
</items>
```

Basically for the rectangle line, whether or not I put dynamic the height of the rectangle is 10 (the border around the text). So how can I make the rectangle the same height as the string-field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible** to dynamically set the height of a line item with a border around it.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the attribute `height="10"` from the `Rectangle`, you will get what you are expecting.

Comment: Removing the height="10" attributes only causes the rectangle to disappear. It doesn't adjust the height dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to ask the obvious, have you tried height="100%" instead of height="10"?

Comment: You can't do that because the rectangle will then take 100% of the height of the page.